# SQL Server Integration Services динамический DataFlow

Tags: sql, sql-server, integration-services

Допустим , имеется пакет, который имеет параметры:

1)Извлекаемая процедура(SQl Server)

2)Таблица(MS Access) в которую засунуть извлеченные данные

Можно ли сделать так, что бы при смене процедуры(Добавлении колонок) и смены выходной базы(Согласно шаблону) пакет работал?

Если не ошибаюсь маппинг колонок делается в момент сборки пакета.

Конечно можно использовать Task с C# кодом, но может быть это можно сделать стандартными примитивами?

Речь идет о MS SQL Server 2008r2

Answer (score 1):

Можно, при условии, что набор полей и их свойств (имен, типов данных) в источнике и получателе меняться не будет. Тогда вы проектируете типовой пакет с параметрами. Если же набор полей или их свойств отличается - вам нужно разбить пары "процедура-таблица" на наборы с одинаковыми свойствами и создать типовые пакеты для каждого набора.
Поясню сказанное. При запуске пакета или при выполнении задачи (управляется свойством delayvaliadtion) производится валидация задачи или всех задач пакета. Если при валидации пакета обнаружится расхождение между внешними метаданными (источник или получатель данных) и внутренними, пакет выпадет в ошибку валидации.